# Can taylor series have $x$ with higher powers?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + 4x^2}$ my professor said,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n 4^n (x^{2n})$$

Is the taylor series (about x=0). But I thought it was in the form $x^n$?

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-4x^2\right)^n=\dfrac1{1-(-4x^2)}$$ for $|4x^2|<1$

Comment: It is in the form $x^n$, it's just the case here that all coefficients for uneven $n$ are zero.

Answer (score 2):

The point is, that series **is** of the form 
$$ \sum_k a_k x^k $$
for 
$$ a_k = \begin{cases} (-1)^{k}4^k & k = 2n \text{ is even}\\
       0 & \text{$k$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
and one usually drops terms equal to $0$ in a sum.

Answer (score 0):

The taylor series (about 0) of $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ is $1+x+x^2+...$ as you probably know. Now, in your case we get $\dfrac{1}{1-(-4x^2)}=1+(-4x^2)+(-4x^2)^2+...$. He have then just "taken out" the $-1$ from the $4$ to get $(-1)^n4^n$ and used that $(x^2)^n=x^{2n}$. Hopefully you can fill in the rest.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(0)\ne0,\\
f'(0)=-\left.\frac{8x}{1+4x^2}\right|_{x=0}=0,\\
f''(0)=\left.\frac{128x^2}{(4x^2+1)^3}-\frac8{(4x^2+1)^2}\right|_{x=0}\ne0,\\\cdots$$

nothing special.